# Jquery .uniqueId() assigns a widget an id thats already used

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

If I have the existing HTML in my page:

```
<p id="ui-id-1">foo</p>
```

Then I run the JS code:

```
 $('<p>bar</p>').appendTo('body').uniqueId();
```

Then that new `p` element gets the id `ui-id-1`. I would expect JQuery UI to be smart enough to allocate an unused id? Am I doing something wrong or is this designed JQuery UI behaviour?

Comment: I don't know much about jquery uniquId but if you know the pattern used by jquery I suggest you to not set an id with the same pattern.

Comment: @Striped, my usecase is; I use `uniqueId()` to create a design, save it. Then a user will reload the design and add to it (again, usin `uniqueId()`).

Comment: I don't have a good solution to provide but a work around could be to save the ids previously used in localstorage or somewhere else and to generate a new unique id checking the saved ones.

Answer (score 1):

You can always workaround to suit your needs.

```js
var uniqueId = $.fn.extend({
  uniqueId: (function() {
    var uuid = 0;
    return function() {
      return this.each(function() {
        this.id = (function r() {
          return !$("#ui-id-" + (++uuid)).length ? "ui-id-" + uuid : r();
        })();
      });
    };
  })()
});
$('<p>bar</p>').appendTo('body').uniqueId();
$('<p>bar</p>').appendTo('body').uniqueId();
$('<p>bar</p>').appendTo('body').uniqueId();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="ui-id-1">foo</p>
<p id="ui-id-3">foo</p>
```

Note: I have not added the source of `removeUniqueId`, if you are using the functionality from `removeUniqueId`, you can add it from the source.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that jQuery-UI keeps track of every id it generate using `uniqueId()`. When a new id is generated, it avoids using existing ids that it has been keeping tracked. But there is a situation in which if you provided an id manually for some element in the format that jQuery-UI uses, new uniqueId generation may duplicate the same ID

```js
var div1 = $("#div-1");
var div2 = $("#div-2");

$("<p>bar</p>").appendTo(div1);
div1.find("p").uniqueId();

$("<p>bar</p>").appendTo(div2);
div2.find("p").uniqueId();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="div-1">
    <p id="ui-id-1">foo</p>    
</div>

<div id="div-2">
    <p>foo</p>    
</div>
```

Output html would be :

```
<div id="div-1">
    <p id="ui-id-1">foo</p>
    <p id="ui-id-1">bar</p>  
</div>

<div id="div-2">
    <p id="ui-id-2">foo</p> 
    <p id="ui-id-3">bar</p>  
</div>
```